# Is $p(Y|X) p(\omega) = p(Y|X,w)$ true?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, conditional-probability

Given a distribution $p(Y|X)$ and a distribution $p(\omega)$, which are independent from eachother.

Is then $p(Y|X) p(\omega) = p(Y|X,w)$ true?

If not, are their any rules to calculate $p(Y|X) p(\omega)$?

**EDIT:**

Im reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02157), and in it Im investigating on the *log evidence lower bound* (ELBO) (section 2.3.):

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{VI} := \int q(\omega)\log p(Y|X,\omega)d\omega - \textbf{KL}(q(\omega) || p(\omega)).
\end{align*}

$\omega$ are parameters of a function $f^{\omega}(x)=y$.
I was trying to derive the ELBO equation by using the Bayes Theorem:

\begin{align*}
p(Y|X,\omega) = \frac{p(X,\omega|Y)p(Y)}{p(X,\omega)}
\end{align*}

(if this is even correct!). And I wondered if its even possible to multiplicate these two distributions as asked in my question.

**EDIT 2:**

I was confused about how to apply Bayes' Theorem to conditional distributions, I corrected my calculations and derived the ELBO now in the following way:

\begin{align}
   \textbf{KL}(q(\pmb{\omega}) || p(\pmb{\omega}|\textbf{X})) &:= \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log \left( \frac{q(\pmb{\omega})}{p(\pmb{\omega}|\textbf{X,Y})} \right) d\pmb{\omega} \nonumber\\
   &= - \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log \left( \frac{p(\pmb{\omega}|\textbf{X,Y})}{q(\pmb{\omega})} \right) d\pmb{\omega} \nonumber\\
   &= - \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log \left( \frac{p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\pmb{\omega})p(\pmb{\omega}|\textbf{X})}{p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}) q(\pmb{\omega})} \right) d\pmb{\omega} \nonumber\\
   &= - \left( \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log \left( \frac{p(\pmb{\omega})}{q(\pmb{\omega})} \right) d\pmb{\omega} - \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log \left( \frac{p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\pmb{\omega})}{p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X})} \right) d\pmb{\omega} \right) \nonumber\\
   &=- \underbrace{\int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log \left( \frac{p(\pmb{\omega})}{q(\pmb{\omega})} \right) d\pmb{\omega} }_{=: \text{ELBO}} + \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log \left( \frac{p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\pmb{\omega})}{p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X})} \right) d\pmb{\omega} \nonumber\\
   &= - \text{ELBO} + \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log ( p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\pmb{\omega}) ) d\pmb{\omega} - \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log ( p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}) ) d\pmb{\omega}   \nonumber\\
   &= - \text{ELBO} + \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log ( p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\pmb{\omega}) ) d\pmb{\omega} - \log ( p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}) ) \underbrace{\int q(\pmb{\omega}) d\pmb{\omega}}_{=1}. \nonumber
\end{align}

Since $\textbf{KL}\geq 0$ (positive definite), ELBO defines a lower bound of $\textbf{KL}$:

\begin{align}
    \textbf{KL}(q(\pmb{\omega}) || p(\pmb{\omega}|\textbf{X})) \geq \text{ELBO}.
\end{align}

$\textit{ELBO}$ is called the $\textit{evidence lower bound}$, because it defines a lower bound of the KL-divergence.
Minimizing the KL-divergence is equivalent to maximizing the ELBO. 
Since we do not have access to the posterior for minimizing the KL-divergence, we should maximize the ELBO instead.
The ELBO as defined above can be rearranged to

\begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}_{\text{VI}} := \text{ELBO} = \int q(\pmb{\omega}) \log ( p(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\pmb{\omega}) ) d\pmb{\omega} -  \textbf{KL}(q(\pmb{\omega}) || p(\pmb{\omega}|\textbf{X})) + \text{const.} 
\end{align}

giving us a likelihood that we can maximize, resulting in an optimal variational distribution (i.e. approximative posterior distribution) $q(\pmb{\omega})$.

Comment: 1) It doesn't really make sense to say that the distributions $p(y \mid x)$ and $p(\omega)$ are independent. Could you clarify the independence assumptions you want to make? This would take the form of statements about the marginal and/or conditional independence of the *random variables* $X,Y,\omega$. 2) Calculate $p(y \mid x) p(\omega)$ from what?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3702729/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom good catch :) Since the question is cross-related, I thought of reaching a greater audience.

Comment: @user20160 thanks for your comment! I edited my question for further precision

Comment: If you mean random variable $\omega$ is independent of RV $\beta=Y|X$, then shouldn't $P(Y|X,\omega)=P(Y|X)$?

Comment: @Tbone yes, absolutely right. I found I was confused about how to apply Bayes Theorem to a conditional distribution, I edited it accordingly. Actually all is clear to me now, there is nothing more to answer :)